# Swift how to animate from new position in animation block?

Tags: ios, swift, animation, switch-statement

I have an animation set up where I change the alpha channel based on a variable

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {() -> Void in
                switch state {
                case 0:
                    self.alpha = 1.0
                case 1:
                    if category != 1 {
                        self.alpha = 0.28
                    }
                case 2:
                    if category != 2 {
                        self.alpha = 0.28
                    }
                case 3:
                    if category != 3 {
                        self.alpha = 0.28
                    }
                default:
                    break
                }
            }, completion: { _ in })
```

However, I've noticed that every time the variable changes, the alpha channel jolts back to `1.0` before animating again. This gets you a jittery animation.

I'm trying to have it animate from whatever alpha channel it is currently at, because with the code I'm using it always animates from **1.0 -> new value** , instead of animating from **current value -> new value**

Comment: are you sure it doesnt go to every single block of switch? and is alpha a declared var or a property of a customView ?

Comment: Have you put `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` at the end of the animation block?

Comment: Now that I realize it, self is a cell in a `collectionView`, and the `collectionView` reloads every time the variable changes. Could this be the reason why the alpha always defaults back to 1.0?

Comment: @baxu - Sound like a good hypothesis. Do some debugging, insert break-points to make sure

Comment: alpha is the `collectionViewCell` property @Aragunz

Comment: Then i need more info, when it is triggered this block etc, do u have it in one single cell or it happens when scrolling and on other cells etc.

Comment: Yes, the animation occurs on scrolling. For every new cell it checks the value number and updates the data. but the problem isn't on scrolling, its only when I reload the collectionView with the new variable @Aragunz